# Asset Pipeline problems on certain images in Rails 4.2 after upgrade from 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

In my Rails 4.2.3 application, I use a jQuery plugin called `Gritter` to deliver messages to the browser.

However, after this recent upgrade to 4.2.3, the background image for Gritter is no longer showing up. The CSS is:

```
.gritter-item {
    display:block;
    background:url(/assets/gritter.png) no-repeat left -40px;
    color:#eee;
    padding:2px 11px 8px 11px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family:verdana;
}
```

Gritter is located in:

```
/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-plugins/Gritter/
```

And there are `css` and `images` directories under that.

So that `url(/assets/gritter.png)` type path assignments are not working. They were originally `url(../images/gritter.png)`. But I tried going back to that and it's not working either.

I have this set up in `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ie-spacer.gif gritter.png gritter-close.png )
```

Something about the asset pipeline has changed in Rails 4, and I don't know what it is.

***UPDATE***

I can see the thumbprinted images in:

```
/public/assets/jquery-plugins/Gritter/images
```

So the problem isn't their inclusion. The problem is that the CSS for this plugin, regardless of even if I include it in my main `application.scss` file,  ***refuses to include the real asset path to the images upon compilation of the CSS***. It can not find the thumbprinted filename.

Comment: Did you try giving the complete path like this: https://gist.github.com/mrbongiolo/63cce06b1b49c99fdb9a

Comment: I've tried everything. 4 hours into this problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you precompile your images assets you need to access them using `asset-url` helper so try:

```
background: asset-url('gritter.png') no-repeat left -40px;
```

Comment: This worked great. The other answers on this page did not work for me. This worked immediately. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**put a space  between background:<space>url(/assets/gritter.png) no-repeat left -40px;**

*Example:* background: url(/assets/gritter.png) no-repeat left -40px;

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this for your background property:

`background: image-url("gritter.png") no-repeat left -40px;`